# Brute Force Algorithm Won't Yield Correctly; Otherwise Works Fine

Tags: recursion, python-3.x, yield, brute-force

I'm trying to find a way to write a fixed length (for now) brute force generator that I can activate preferably like this.

```
for i in FixedLength('abc', 3):
    print(i);
```

The value of i should not be a generator.  This is what I have:

```
import sys;
class FixedLength:  
    def __init__(self, charset, length, code_page=sys.getdefaultencoding())
        self.length=length;
        self.code_page=code_page;
        #basically
        self.charset=bytes(charset, code_page);
        self.retval=[charset[0]]*length;

    def __iter__(self):
        return self;

    def __next__(self):
        #problem line 1
        self.recurse(0);
        raise StopIteration;

    def recurse(self, recursion_level):
        if recursion_level==self.length-1:
            for char in self.charset:
                self.retval[recursion_level]=char;
                if self.validate():
                    #problem line 2
                    yield self.output();
        else:
            for char in self.charset:
                self.retval[recursion_level]=char;
                self.recurse(recursion_level+1);
    def validate(self):
        return True;
    def output(self):
        return bytes(self.retval).decode(self.code_page);
```

I know it will print the output (from problem line 2) just fine but I can't get it to yield the same info.  Yielding problem line 1 packs a generator in a generator.  Returning problem line 1 wouldn't work because it wouldn't raise a StopIteration error.  But asside from that it doesn't seem to actually recurse.  Although, it does call self.recurse repeatedly the recursion level stays at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your `recurse` is a generator function.  When called, it produces a sequence.  If your `__next__` wants to return the next value of the sequence, it must get the next value from the `recurse`:

```
def __next__(self):
    next(self.recurse(0))
```

The built-in `next()` also raises the `StopIteration` exception.

However, the design is a bit confused. It mixes generator with your attempt to implement the similar.  In other words, you are wrapping one generator into another.  Or, you are implementing the iterator recursively, which is odd.  Or I am confused.  What is the intention?  It can probably be implemented in a simpler way.

Comment: I'm trying to nest any number of `for` statements without actually typing them out manually every time.  Is that a bad idea? I don't see any other way to implement this other than recursion (except `eval` but that never seems right).

Comment: I do not know if it is good or bad idea because I do not know the exact problem that you try to solve. Can you describe it better? Is there a reason to define a class for the purpose? The generators are the kind of doing the same without the class (i.e. the alternative; the iterator class is hidden in the implementation).